# Latency for Geocoding API

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I was planning to use `Google Geocoding API`. I was wondering what is the latency I should expect in getting the response back? I cannot find out these details on the [website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Geocoding).

Does anyone aware of what will be the actual latency if I am using Google Geocoding API?

Meaning how much time it will take to get the response back from the Geocoding API.

Comment: Can I ask you why you need to know that ? That can vary, depending on many factors.

Comment: Surely it would have to be slower than the navigator.geolocation method because of the round trip

Comment: Why I am asking this, it might be possible that we are planning to use this API in our Production environment. So for that there are some clients asking for 250ms latency for this. So that is the reason I was asking this. I know there are several factors it will depend on. But in general there should be some number for that right  approximately? A genuine question shouldn't be voted to get closed.

Comment: you probably would expect about 500ms for a round trip.  that # comes from our experience from a aws server. which the # looks a little bit high than i would expect.

Answer (score 4):

we have a live app working in the playstore and we get roughly 120-150 hits per hour. Our median latency is around 210 ms and latency (98%) is 510 ms.

Answer (score 2):

We have an application 24x7 with ~2 requests per second.

Median: 197.08 ms
98th percentile (slowest 2%): 490.54  ms

Could be a high bottle neck for you application... use some strategies to help you:

- Memory cache
- Secondary cache
- batch persistence

[image: Geocoding API Latency]

[image: Requests]